# Use pretrained model with different input shape and class model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, supervised-learning

I am working on a classification problem using `CNN` where my input image size is `64X64` and I want to use pretrained model such as *VGG16*,*COCO* or any other. But the problem is input image size of pretrained model is `224X224`. How do I sort this issue. Is there any data augmentation way for input image size.

If I resize my input image to `224X224` then there is very high chance of image will get blurred and that may impact the training. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Another question is related to pretrained model. If I am using `transfer learning` then generally how layers I have to freeze from pretrained model. Considering my classification is very different from pretrained model classes. But I guess first few layers we can freeze it to get the edges, curve etc.. of the images which is very common in all the images.

Answer (score 12):

> But the problem is input image size of pretrained model is 224X224.

I assume you work with `Keras`/`Tensorflow` (It's the same for other DL frameworks). According to the docs in the [Keras Application](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg19):

> **input_shape**: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top
> is False (otherwise the input shape has to be  (224, 224, 3) (with
> 'channels_last' data format) or (3, 224, 224) (with 'channels_first'
> data format). It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and
> height should be no smaller than 48. E.g. (200, 200, 3) would be one

So there are two options to solve your issue:

1. Resize your input image to `244*244` by [existing library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use **VGG** classifier [`include_top=True`].
2. Train your own classifier on top of the VGG models. As mentioned in the above documentation in `Keras` if your image is different than 244*244, you should train your own classifier `[include_top=False]`. You can do such things easily with:

   ```
    inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3), name='image_input')

    vgg_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    vgg_model.trainable = False

    x = keras.layers.Flatten(name='flatten')(vgg_model)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    new_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
    new_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
   ```

> If I am using transfer learning then generally how layers I have to
> freeze from pretrained model

It is really depend on what your new task, how many training example you have, whats your pretrained model, and lots of other things. If I were you, I first throw away the pretrained model classifier. Then, If not worked, remove some other Convolution layer and do it step by step until I get good performance.

Comment: 1) Resizing of an image may lose features of the image. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 2)Sorry, I am new to deep learning.What does below 2 line means? So we are not using top layer of VGG models. Then,could you please explain how VGG model is impacting layers that you have defined above.                                                           vgg_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    vgg_model.trainable = False

Comment: @PankajKumar change image from 64 to 244 is risky as a result you probably loss some features. In those two line, first I load pretrained model (VGG) and freezed the model (its not trainable). You only trained the classifier not whole model.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, Did you solve it? For e.g. I have Pretrained weights on images of 64*64 pixels. I would like to do transfer learning on new images of resolution 128*128 pixels. How can I do this? the similar way as 2)? and what about the spatial size?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me for image size 128*128*3:

```
vgg_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
print(vgg_model.summary())

#Get the dictionary of config for vgg16
vgg_config = vgg_model.get_config()

vgg_config["layers"][0]["config"]["batch_input_shape"] = (None, 128, 128, 3)

vgg_updated = Model.from_config(vgg_config)
vgg_updated.trainable = False

model = Sequential()
 
# Add the vgg convolutional base model
model.add(vgg_updated)

# Flattedn Layer must be added
model.add(Flatten())

vgg_updated.summary()
model.summary()
```